# Directory not found exception when hosted on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webmethod

I have a web service that renders PDF from server and converts it into byte stream.

The problem I am encountering is that the web method is not working when hosted on IIS and I don't know what might be the problem because I am not in c#. I just want the response of it and need to display in my android app. The error I get is:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\VAT Publishing\Android_web_service\App_Data\Order_Copy\303900816_Appl_Application.pdf'.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>      at officer_auth.GetFile(String filename)

and my code is as follows

```
 public byte[] GetFile(string filename)
{
   // byte[] binFile = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };
    string src = "\\\\182.10.0.10\\d$\\abc_Files\\" + filename.ToString();
    string dest = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Order_Copy/") + "\\" + filename.ToString();
    FileInfo theFile = new FileInfo(src);
    try
    {
        foreach (string file1 in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Order_Copy/"), "*.pdf"))
        {
            try { File.Delete(file1); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
    if (theFile.Exists)
    {
        File.Copy(src, dest);

    }


    BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Order_Copy/") + "\\" + filename.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    binReader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] binFile = binReader.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(binReader.BaseStream.Length));
    binReader.Close();
    return binFile;
}
```

Comment: Where this exception is being thrown exactly?

Comment: after I enter the file name and click on invoke button i am getting the following exception..

Comment: I mean could you point the exact line in you code example?

Comment: the code is working fine when i run it through visual basics its giving me the desired output..but when i trying hosting it on iis its giving an exception...

Comment: Are you sure that `D:\VAT Publishing\Android_web_service\App_Data\Order_Copy\303900816_Appl_Application.pdf` exists?

Comment: Instead of accessing the source as d$ - share the folder and then try to access it

Comment: @Kamo ya it does exist.

Comment: scratch the previous comment no it doesnt exist i am not able to locate my appdata folder

Comment: hence it is throwing the exception...can u please suggest a solution for it

Comment: Are you deploying your application using `Publish` functionality?

Comment: i am doing Build->>publish website then copying the published folder in the drive but after publishing i am not hetting my app data folder

Comment: Is changing `App_Data` to some different folder available to you?

Comment: @Kamo the thing is that i am getting the app_data folder when i publish it but i am not getting the pdf in side it...